# All squares that match a wildcard sequence

Tags: code-golf, string, math

This was inspired by part of the 2016 ARML competition Team Problem #6.

Here's the challenge:

You're given a "wildcard sequence", which is a sequence of digits and another character. A string matches this wildcard sequence by the following pseudocode:

```
w = wildcard
s = string
# s matches w iff
for all 0 >= i > wildcard.length, w[i] == '?' or s[i] == w[i]
```

Where '?' is a character of your choice.

In terms of regex, just imagine the `'?'` to be `'.'`.

The challenge is to find all square numbers (the requirement is up to 1 million) whose decimal string representations match this wildcard sequence. The "wildcard character" can be any ASCII character of your choice, as long as it isn't a digit, obviously.

For example, `4096` matches `4**6` and `4*9*` but `4114` does not match either.

### Input

Input will be given as a sequence matching the regex `[0-9?]+`. This can be a string, a character array, or a byte array of the characters in ASCII.

### Output

Output will be a whatever-you-want-delimited list/set/array of numbers which are perfect squares and match the wildcard sequence.

### Examples of valid inputs:

```
1234567*90
1234567?90
1234567u90
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '*', '9', '0']
[49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 42, 57, 48]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, '*', 9, 0]
```

### Examples of valid outputs:

```
[1, 4, 9]
1 4 9
1, 4, 9
1-4-9
```

etc.

### Specifications

- You may not use builtins for finding a list of squares in a certain range
- [Standard Loopholes Apply](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)
- You must be able to handle up to 1 000 000 (1 million)
- If provided with the input `1******`, it is correct to print `[1000000]`. It is also correct to print `[1000000, 1002001, 1004004, 1006009, 1008016, 1010025, ...]`
- Wildcard sequences will never start with the wildcard character; that is, they will always match strings of the same length.

### Test Cases

```
4**6  ->  [4096, 4356]
1**1  ->  [1521, 1681]
1**  ->  [100, 121, 144, 169, 196]
9****9  ->  [908209, 915849, 927369, 935089, 946729, 954529, 966289, 974169, 986049, 994009]
9*9***  ->  [919681, 929296]
1**0*  ->  [10000, 10201, 10404, 10609, 12100, 14400, 16900, 19600]
9***4  ->  [91204, 94864, 97344]
```

### Winning

Shortest (valid) (working) submission by February 14th, tie-break by earliest submission winning.

Comment: I think a good start to making this clearer would be to specify that `?` is to be chosen by the answerer.

Comment: Why is `25` a valid answer for `***` but not for `*2*`?

Comment: I think this would be cleaner if the numbers never had leading zeroes, so only matched sequences of their length.

Comment: @Neil That would be a problem with my own solution. I'll take xnor's suggestion.

Comment: Can the input be an array of one-digit integers and the special character, such as `{4, "w", "w", 6}` (or better yet, `{4, w, w, 6}`), rather than an array of characters, such as `{"4", "w", "w", "6"}`?

Comment: @GregMartin Sure. I'll add that into the challenge.

Comment: @WheatWizard I've changed the explanation. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: @AlexL. I think figured out the challenge before the change was made but to be honest I don't know if the edit helps terribly much.  I think all that was needed was an explanation of what a wildcard sequence was and a little more clarification about the output.  Until I read it a fourth or fifth time I didn't know that "squares" meant square numbers.

Comment: @WheatWizard ohhhhhh Whoops, I made the classic mistake of reading what I thought instead of what I actually read.

Comment: "*The challenge is to find all square numbers whose decimal string representations match this wildcard sequence*" and "*If provided with the input `1******`, it is correct to print `[1000000]`*" contradict each other.

Comment: @PeterTaylor That is a good point. I should clariy that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 22 bytes

Probably plenty of room for improvement here.
Any non-digit is okay as wildcard.

```
3°LnvyS¹)ø€Æ0QPyg¹gQ&—
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@298aINPXlll8KGdmod3PGpac7jNIDCgMv3QzvRAtUcNU/7/j1a3VNdR10LCJuqxAA)

Explanation to come after further golfing.

Comment: This appears to work for all inputs. Good job.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 44 bytes

```
Print@@@IntegerDigits[Range@1*^3^2]~Cases~#&
```

The input is a list of digits with a `_` (no quotes) as a wildcard. e.g. `{4, _, _, 6}`

**Explanation**

```
Range@1*^3
```

Generate list `{1, 2, 3, ... , 1000}`

```
... ^2
```

Square it. (list of all squares from 1 to 1,000,000)

```
IntegerDigits[ ... ]
```

Split each square into a list of digits.

```
... ~Cases~#
```

Find the ones that match the pattern specified by the input.

```
Print@@@ ...
```

Print them.

Comment: This appears to work for all test cases. Good job.

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 23 bytes

```
@e:{@$|,}a#0:{c.~^#I,}f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog#@@@QalXtoFKjU5uobGBVnaxXF6fsqVOb9v@/kqWWlpaJ0v8oAA)

#### Explanation

```
@e                        Split into a list of characters
  :{@$|,}a                Replace each digit char by the corresponding digit, and each things
                            that are ot digits into variables
          #0              All elements of the resulting list must be digits
            :{       }f   Output is the result of finding all...
              c.            ...concatenations of those digits which...
               .~^#I,       ...result in a number which is the square of an integer #I
```

#### Different input format, 13 bytes

Depending on what your consider valid as input, you could do this:

```
#0:{c.~^#I,}f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog#@69sYFWdrFcXp@ypU5v2/3@0pZWjlZOVs5VJ7P8oAA)

which is basically the second part of the answer above, with a list as input containing digits and variables where the wildcards are.

I don't consider this valid though because there are only 26 variable names in Brachylog (the uppercase letters), so this would not work if you had more than 26 wilcards.

Comment: This appears to work for all inputs. Good job. However, I would consider this to be 24 bytes because a 1-byte argument is required. I'm not sure how scoring for this would work though.

Comment: @AlexL. The argument is only there to tell the name of the output variable (you can use another uppercase letter if you want). This is similar to answers in Prolog/languages with functions where the predicate/function is named but you don't actually count the bytes you use when you call it.

Comment: Okay. I'm not sure if one should score it as 24 since the argument is necessary (otherwise it just returns `true.`), but I haven't used languages that require this before. I'll try to find some reference to determine how I should score this, but it would make sense to score it as 23, so I'll keep it at that.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 54 bytes

Function that takes a string argument. [Try it online.](https://repl.it/FJCV)

```
->s{(0..1e3).map{|i|"#{i**2}"[/^#{s.tr ?*,?.}$/]}-[p]}
```

Comment: You could save a byte by using i*i instead of i**2

Comment: This doesn't appear to work because the second `#` is making the rest of the line a comment.

Comment: @AlexL Oh, it works all right. https://repl.it/FJCV

Comment: ohhhh okay I just didn't know how to test Ruby. My apologies. This appears to work for all input. Good job!

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), <s>30</s> 26 bytes

*Thanks to @b2gills for -4 bytes!*

```
{grep /^<$_>$/,map * **2,^1e4}
```

```
{grep /^<$_>$/,(^1e4)»²}
```

Uses the dot as wildcard character, so that the input can be used as a regex:

```
{                            }   # a lambda
                         ^1e4    # range from 0 to 9999
               map * **2,        # square each value
 grep /      /,                  # filter numbers that match this regex:
        <$_>                     #   lambda argument eval'ed as sub-regex
       ^    $                    #   anchor to beginning and end
```

[Try it online](https://glot.io/snippets/em5hsxv0ft).

A variant that accepts the asterisk as wildcard (as suggested by a previous revision of the task description) would be 42 bytes:

```
{grep /^<{.trans("*"=>".")}>$/,(^1e4)»²}
```

Comment: I've restated the rules, and you can choose any wildcard character. I'm scoring this as 38 bytes.

Comment: Um, how do you use this? I don't know anything about Perl.

Comment: @AlexL.: Thanks, I've updated the answer (and added an explanation too). It's a lambda; you could call it directly (e.g. `{ ... }("9*9***")`), or assign it to a variable/symbol for later use. Note that Perl 6 is a separate language from Perl, so it won't work with a Perl interpreter.

Comment: I used `sudo apt-get install rakudo` to get a supposed Perl6 interpreter... When I put `perl6` as a command into my terminal, it starts what seems to be a Perl6 interpreter, but I don't know how to use it. I know it's a lambda, but I don't know how to call it.

Comment: @AlexL.: I added a "Try it online" link which shows it as a full script that you can run as `perl6 foo.p6`. You can also test it in a shell oneliner, like `perl6 -e 'say {grep /^<$_>$/,map * **2,^1e4}( "9.9..." )'`

Comment: This appears to work for all test cases. Good job.

Comment: This can be shortened to 26 bytes [`{grep /^<$_>$/,(^1e4)»²}`](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#Ky1OVSgz00u25uJKyy9SyMnMSy3W0FSoVihOrFTQU9P4X51elFqgoB9noxJvp6KvoxFnmGqieWj3oU21/zVr/5vo6ZlxGerpGYIILks9ILAEUiAGSMQAImYCAA)

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills: Neat, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>68</s> 66 bytes

**EDIT:** Updated my solution below after being inspired by [JungHwan Min's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106646/11182). It is now ES6 compliant.

Takes input in the format `'1..4'` where `.` is the wildcard.

Instead of iterating to 1e6 and square rooting this one iterates to 1e3 and squares.

```js
p=>[...Array(1e3)].map((_,n)=>''+n*n).filter(n=>n.match(`^${p}$`))
```

```js
F=p=>[...Array(1e3)].map((_,n)=>''+n*n).filter(n=>n.match(`^${p}$`))

const update = () => {
  console.clear();
  console.log(F(input.value));
}

submit.onclick = update;
update();
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" value="9....9" style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box" /><button id="submit">submit</button>
```

## JavaScript (ES7), <s>71</s> 69 bytes

```js
p=>[...Array(1e6).keys()].filter(n=>n**.5%1?0:(''+n).match(`^${p}$`))
```

Creates an array of numbers from 0 to 1e6 then filters it by numbers that are square and match the pattern.

It is horrendously slow because it always iterates to 1e6.

```js
F=p=>[...Array(1e6).keys()].filter(n=>n**.5%1?0:(''+n).match(`^${p}$`))

const update = () => {
  console.clear();
  console.log(F(input.value));
}

submit.onclick = update;
update();
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" value="9....9" style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box" /><button id="submit">submit</button>
```

Comment: I don't think `**` is working, because it's giving me a `"SyntaxError: expected expression, got '*'"`.

Comment: @AlexL. The rules seem to have changed. The previous rules suggested I could choose the wildcard character.

Comment: You only need to support up to `1e6`...

Comment: Additionally, I changed the rules back; the issue isn't with the rules, it's because the `**` operator doesn't exist, at least not with my system.

Comment: @AlexL. Ah sorry I thought you meant the input `**`. Yes it is ES7 I will update title here is a list of currently supported browsers https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Okay. That clarifies the issue.

Comment: This appears to work for all test cases. Good job.

Comment: up to 1 million should mean managing 1 million too. It fails for `1......` (not hard to fix)

Comment: and using `match` instead of `!search` should save 2 bytes

Comment: @edc65 Thanks didn't realise that did string to regex conversion too.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, <strike>42</strike> <strike>45</strike> 38 bytes

EDIT: clarification by Alex, we can use the period as wildcard character which shaves off the y// operation.

```
perl -pe 's|.*|@{[grep/^$&$/,map$_*$_,1..1e3]}|'
```

EDIT: solution that uses the asterisk as wildcard character and expects the wildcard sequence on STDIN

```
perl -pe 'y/*/./;s|.*|@{[grep/^$&$/,map$_*$_,1..1e3]}|'
```

This one leaves undoubtedly a lot of room for improvement, it's pretty straightforward. The wildcard expression is expected as command line argument, with the period wildcard character (what else?).

```
say"@{[grep/^$ARGV[0]$/,map$_*$_,1..1e3]}"
```

Comment: The question specifies that wildcards are given as asterisks. Did an earlier revision of the question allow choosing your own wildcard character?

Comment: @smls: The question still specifies choose your own wildcard although it is not in the rule section: *The character used as the wildcard doesn't necessarily need to be an asterisk, it can be any ASCII character of your choice, as long as it isn't a digit, obviously.*

Comment: Yes, I got confused by that. Later on, it clearly says the wildcard character needs to be an asterisk. I guess the definition with the regex is leading. I'll revise my solution.

Comment: Hm actually, the sentence quoted by @Emigna is pretty clear that we *can* choose our own wildcard character, isn't it?

Comment: To clarify, the wildcard character can be whatever you want. I accidentally messed up the rules when restating the explanation.

Comment: @Alex L: thanks for the clarification. Could you edit the rules so that it's clear? I tried to comment there but as a newbie I couldn´t.

Comment: This appears to work for all inputs. Good job.

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 109 bytes

```
@for /l %%i in (0,1,999)do @set/aj=%%i*%%i&call copy nul %%j%%.%%j%%$>nul
@for %%s in (%1.%1$)do @echo %%~ns
```

Uses `?` as the wildcard. Works by creating 1000 files. The name of the file is the square number, and the extension of the file is the square number with a `$` suffixed. This is because Batch's pattern matching counts trailing `?`s as optional, so `1?` will match both `1` and `16`; the `$` therefore forces the match to be exact. However, we don't want to output the `$`, so we just output the file name only without extension.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3 - <s>98</s> 97 bytes

```
import re;print(re.findall(r"\b"+input()+r"\b",("\n".join([str(x*x) for x in range(1,1001)]))))
```

Requires input like '4..6'.

Comment: You can save 3 bytes by using `import re` and `re.findall`; the optimization with the `from...import *` doesn't actually optimize it in this case.

Comment: Provided input `1....`, it gives `1 4 9` and `16 25` as valid answers, which is not correct. Please correct your program.

Comment: Fixet the case by joining on "\n".

Comment: This doesn't work for `1......`. It returns `[]`, but it should give `[1000000]`. This can be fixed at a cost of 0 bytes by using `range(0, 1001)` rather than `range(0, 1000)`.

Comment: Good point, I just checked all the test cases from the description :)

Comment: This appears to work for all input. Good job.

Answer (score 0):

## k - 28 characters

```
{s(&:)($:s:s*s:!1001)like x}
```

Uses `?` as the wildcard character. The `like` function uses `?` as a wildcard, and this function makes a list of the first 1001 squares (to be inclusive to 1M), casts them all to strings, and then checks where they match the pattern.

```
    {s(&:)($:s:s*s:!1001)like x} "1??"
100 121 144 169 196
```

Comment: I'm getting this error for it: `type error
{s(&:)($:s:s*s:!1001)like x} "1"
at execution instance 2 of ":"`. Could you provide a link to a working test suite or see if there's a problem?

Comment: @AlexL. It works for me in kdb+'s k mode

Comment: Hmm. I'll try testing it with different interpreters.

Answer (score 0):

## bash + Unix utilities, 33 bytes

```
dc<<<'0[2^pv1+lax]dsax'|grep ^$1$
```

This uses '.' as the wildcard character.

The dc program prints the square numbers in an infinite loop:

```
0     Push 0 on the stack.

[     Start a macro (called a).

2^    Square the number at the top of the stack.

p     Print the number at the top of the stack, followed by a newline.

v     Replace the number at the top of the stack (a square number) with its square root.

1+    Increment the number at the top of the stack.

lax   Run the macro again (looping).

]     End of the macro.

dsax  Store the macro in register a and run it.
```

The dc output is piped to grep, which prints just the squares that match the required pattern.

This works when I run it on an actual Linux or OS X system (but it doesn't work at TIO, probably because the dc program tries to recurse forever, and I suspect TIO runs out of stack space for the recursion and/or has a problem with the never-ending pipe).

Comment: I'm running this with Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa, and it's not terminating. I think the problem is with the never-ending `dc` command.

Comment: I suspect it's actually the buffering that's causing the issue. I don't have that version of Linux, but you could try replacing the grep with   grep --line-buffered    (to cause each line to be printed as it's grepped).  [Of course, that adds a number of bytes.]

Comment: I added the grep argument, but it doesn't make a difference. I tried putting the `--line-buffered` on either side of the `^$1$`, but it doesn't work either way.

Comment: @AlexL.Thank you for trying. I don't know if the difference is in the kernel or in the bash version I'm running. I got it to work in TIO by forcing an end to grep's input using head, as follows: dc<<<'0[2^pv1+lax]dsax'|head -1`sed s/./0/g<<<$1`|grep ^$1$ This uses the length of the pattern to limit the numbers being tested (4-character patterns check only up to 9999, etc.).  Here's a TIO link: https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@SbGNjo24QbRRXUGaonZNYEZtSnFihXpORmpiioGuYUJyaolCsr6dvoJ8OVKhimFCTXpRaoBCnYqjy//9/Ez09PQA

Comment: Thank you for the fix. I don't think the current solution would actually work (though I don't have much knowledge of bash), because it appears that it needs to calculate all values before feeding that into `grep`. However, as it is currently not the shortest solution, I will keep it at 33 bytes for scoring. It appears to work for all inputs, so good job!

Comment: @AlexL. Count it however you're comfortable; it's just for fun, and it's not going to win anyway. It does work in my two test systems--one is OS X and the other is Linux; something must have changed in the more recent kernels, or the more recent bash or grep. The issue appears to be with I/O buffering. Programs in a pipe don't wait for earlier programs to finish (in the version that works on TIO, with the call to head, the dc program is still running forever, but output does get produced).  I/O may wait, however, for a buffer to fill up (or for the other end of the I/O operation to be closed).